# How to get image on the page

Tags: cefsharp

I have been trying to use CefSharp to process html pages for an automation system. I reviewed examples and they englihtened me a bit, but I could not find any clear answer for my problem.

How can I get the image on the page? I need to process images after retrieving by Id. If possible, I do not want to download the image over again. I believe images (resources) are stored somewhere. How can I reach at that store and retrieve image? If there is no way to reach at that store, maybe an interceptor for the request? I may convert image to base64 string and get it with javascript, but I am looking for a better way. Could you offer me a better way to do it? Of course, native C# code.

Any help will be appreciated. If you can provide some sample code links, I will be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CEF` does not provide an `API` to access the cache directly. In `49.0.0` you can get access to the raw data stream for every response. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1519 You could implement a `ResourceHandler` and fulfil the requests yourself (there's examples in the source). If you explicitly need to get them by `Id` then you may find the `Base64` method is the simplest option.

Comment: I tried to do with ResourceHandler, but it seems I cannot get the name of resource in OnCompleted event and some events are receiving data chunk by chunk. Maybe, I have to extend that part of the code in the example. Probably I will stick to converting image to Base64 with javascript and then converting back. It is not an efficient way, but I will try to do it in this way.